# Anyway to tell if perl script is run via do?

Tags: perl

I have a small script configuration file which is loaded from a main script.

```
#main.pl
package MYPACKAGE;
our $isMaster=1;

package main;
my config=do "./config.pl"
```

```
#config.pl
my $runViaDoFlag; 

$runViaDoFlag=$0=~/main\.pl/;                  #Test if main.pl is the executing script
$runViaDoFlag=defined $MYPACKAGE::isMaster;    #Test custom package variable
                                               #Is there a 'built-in' way to do this?

die "Need to run from main script! " unless $runViaDoFlag;

{
    options={
        option1=>"some value",
        option2=>"some value",
    },
    mySub=>sub { 
               # do interesting things here
           }
}
```

In a more complicated config file it might not be so obvious that config.pl script is intended to only be executed by `do`. Hence I want to include a `die` with basic usage instructions.

Solutions:

- test `$0` for the main script name
- have custom package variable defined in the main script and checked by the config script
- simply have a comment in the config instructing the user how to use it.

These work, however is there some way of knowing if a script is executed via do via built-in variable/subs?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `require`? Or, why would you want to exclude `require`? The only difference is that `require` stops you if there's a problem in the code and there's no final true value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd offer a change in design: have that configuration in a normal module, in which you can then test whether it's been loaded by (out of) the `main::` namespace or not.  Then there is no need for any of that acrobatics with control variables etc.

One way to do that

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;          # so to be able to 'use' from current directory

use ConfigPackage qw(load_config);

my $config = load_config();
# ...
```

and the `ConfigPackage.pm` (in the same directory)

```
package ConfigPackage;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Carp;

use Exporter qw();                 # want our own import
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(load_config);

sub import { 
    #say "Loaded by: ", (caller)[0];
    croak "Must only be loaded from 'main::'"
        if not ( (caller)[0] eq 'main' );

    # Now switch to Exporter::import to export symbols as needed
    goto &Exporter::import;
}

sub load_config {
    # ...
    return 'Some config-related data structure';
}

1;
```

(Note that *this* use of [goto](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto) is fine.)

This is just a sketch of course; adjust, develop further, and amend as needed.  If this is lodaed out of a package other than `main::`, and so it fails, then that happens in the compile phase, since that's when [import](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import) is called. I'd consider that a good thing.

If that config code need be able to run as well, as the question may indicate, then have a separate executable that loads this module and runs what need be run.

---

As for the question as stated, the title and the question's (apparent) quest differ a little, but both can be treated by using [caller EXPR](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller). It won't be a clean little "*built-in*" invocation though.

The thing about [do](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do) as intended to be used is that

> `do` '`./stat.pl`' is largely like
>
> ```
> eval `cat stat.pl`;
> ```
>
> except that ...

(That `stat.pl` is introduced earlier in docs, merely to signify that `do` is invoked on a file.)

Then `caller(0)` will have clear hints to offer (see docs). It returns

> ```
> my ($package, $filename, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs,
>     $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask, $hinthash)
> = caller($i);
> ```

In a call asked for, `do './config.pl'`, apart from `main` (package) and the correct filename, the `caller(0)` in `config.pl` also returns:

- `(eval)` for `$subroutine`
- `./config.pl` for `$evaltext`
- `1` for `$is_require`

Altogether this gives plenty to decide whether the call was made as required.

However, I would not recommend this kind of involved analysis instead of just using a package, what is also incomparably more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the details!  `caller` I think is what I need for for my simple script. It turns out `caller` returns an empty array when called at the top level. So simply testing @{[caller]}==0 indicates if my config.pl script was executed directly.